# Tomcat: Setting custom url of servlet (servlet-mapping vs .war-deployment)

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I hope someone can help me with this one. I am running a dummy-servlet on a Tomcat server. This works basically, website is reachable after start.
I would like to specify a custom url e.g. `localhost:8080/mydesiredname`

I deploy my servlet as .war file. It turned out that the name of the .war determines the name of the url under which Tomcat is reachable. If its called `abc` my servlet will run under `localhost:8080/abc`.

While I am not unhappy with this solution I wonder what is the `servlet-mapping` good for in the `<Tomcathome>/conf/web.xml`. I tried to override and/or add an additional url name under which my servlet should be reachable but this does not seem to work.
My code in the web.xml looks like this:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>ABC</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>myservlet.TheServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>ABC</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/otherUrl</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

So I would expect either that my servlet is only reachable by `/otherUrl` or additionally to the url decided by the .war name. I am probably missing something. Can some clarify this for me?

Comment: Do not modify `<Tomcathome>conf/web.xml`. Instead, you should be editing the `WEB-INF/web.xml` file within your own application.

Answer (score 5):

There are two concepts here to understand: the *context path* (where the application can be found) and the *servlet path*.

The *context path* is always relative to the hostname (er, close enough). So if you have your context called `mydesiredname` then you can find it at `https://example.com/mydesiredname`.

All URLs within the application's `WEB-INF/web.xml` are context-relative. That means that if you specify `/ABC` for your servlet's `<url-mapping>` (or *servlet path*) then you would reach that servlet by requesting `https://example.com/mydesiredname/ABC`.

There is no way, within a web application, to respond to a URL that is "outside" your *context path* because the container won't send requests to `https://example.com/ABC` to the web application with *context path* `/mydesiredname`.

If you want to access your servlet using `https://example.com/ABC`, then what you want to do is deploy your web application to the so-called "root" context. In Tomcat, you do that by naming your WAR file `ROOT.war` and the *context path* becomes `""` (an empty string).